# Multi threading and shared object

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, shared-memory

If I have a class like :

```
class MultiThreadEg {

private Member member;

public Integer aMethod() {
    ..............
    ..............
}

public String aThread() {
    ...............
    member.memberMethod(.....);
    Payment py = member.payment();
    py.processPayment();
    ...........................
}

}
```

Suppose that **aThread()** is a new thread, then, will accessing the shared **member** object by too many threads at the same time cause any issues (with the following access rules)?

```
Rule 1 : ONLY reading, no writing to the object(member).
Rule 2 : For all the objects that need some manipulation(writing/modification), a copy of the original object will be created.
```

for eg: In the **payment()** method, I do this :

```
public class Member {

private Payment memPay;

public payment() {
   Payment py = new Payment(this.memPay);//Class's Object copy constructor will be called.
   return py;
}

}
```

My concern is that, even though I create object copies for "writing" (like in the method **payment()**), acessing the **member** object by too many threads at the same time will cause some discrepancies.

What is the fact ? Is this implementation reliable in every case (0 or more concurrent accesses) ? Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a [**ReentrantReadWriteLock**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).  That way, you could have multiple threads reading at the same time, without issue, but only one would be allowed to modify data.  And Java handles the concurrency for you.

```
 ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
 Lock readLock = rwl.readLock;
 Lock writeLock = rwl.writeLock;

 public void read() {

    rwl.readLock.lock();
    try {
       // Read as much as you want.
    } finally {
       rwl.readlock.unlock();
    }
 }

 public void writeSomething() {
    rwl.writeLock.lock();
    try {
       // Modify anything you want
    } finally {
       rwl.writeLock.unlock();
    }
 }
```

Notice that you should *lock()* before the try block begins, to guarantee the lock has been obtained before even starting.  And, putting the *unlock()* in the *finally* clause guarantees that, no matter what happens within the try (early *return,* an exception is thrown, etc), the lock will be released.

Comment: If I lock, other threads will have to wait, which can cause performance issues. So if just reading a shared object or in case of writing, creating a new copy of the object and modifying it wont' cause any issues, I will continue using it. Otherwise I will have to think about something else.

Comment: @M-D so you're saying, if 20 threads call the *payment()* method, there will be 20 identical Payment copies of memPay()?  What's the purpose of that?  Is the Member class more like a factory then?

Comment: Yes, there will be 20 identical copies (or in other words, it will be similar to creating 20 different objects of **Payment**).

Comment: It has a sole purpose : speed. Suppose that there are many cpu intensive tasks that are performed during the creation of either a Payment object or a Member object, then I will have to repeat all those time consuming steps for all the new threads, so I basically do all that in the Constructor, and if any others need a modification of the original, a new copy of the created obect will be created(which takes 1/1000 of time of object creation), in case of just reading, the original object will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In case update to memPay depends on the memPay contents (like memPay.amount+=100) you should block access for other threads when you are updating. This looks like:

```
mutual exclusion block start
get copy
update copy
publish copy
mutual exclusion block end
```

Otherwise there could be lost updates when two threads simultaneously begin update memPay object.

Comment: No, in case of update, I create a new object of **Payment**. Please see the **new** method call. So you mean in case of just reading there will be no issues (even if there are thousands) ?

Comment: That depends on what issues you consider. But generally I do not see any issues if _any_ amount of threads just read memory. `Please see the new method call.` that does not save you from trouble when two threads simultaneously update same object. You may lose updates. For example run several threads which increment same variable in loop: `int shared = 0;` in every thread: `shared++`. After execution that is very likely that value of `shared` would be less than its sequential update scheme variant (no parallel updates as in first variant).

Comment: No,there will be no issues with updation if I do it that way. Because you update on a new object, a copy(to be precise both the copy and the original have different references, but they will have same values for their attributes until I modify the copy). I have tested this but could not test in such a way that there are many accesses at the same time.

Comment: How can you say `No,there will be no issues with updation if I do it that way` if ` could not test in such a way that there are many accesses at the same time`.

Comment: I mean there are no issues at the moment, when I update the copied objects. And theoretically thinking, there will be no issues even if we do it with multiple threads, because all have their own copies (different object references) of the original. However, I just doubt that there may be some issues when there are, say, hundreds of thousands of accesses at the same time. Its just my speculation which I would like to make certain.

Comment: Unless your update does not depend on the updating object contents there will be no issues, but if update _depends_ on objects contents you will have lost updates, and their likeliness will increase as thread amount increases.